# convert string to character powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to build a tool that creates a bootable usb and assign a free drive letter I found here a useful script and did some modification to it

```
$freeletter = get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | select -expand DeviceID -Last 1 | % { [char]([int][char]$_[0]  + 1) + $_[1] }
$splitted = $freeletter -split ":"
[char]$splitted
```

now I have the free drive letter stored in "$splitted" variable 
but when I run the following command

```
New-Partition -DiskNumber $disknumber -UseMaximumSize -IsActive:$true -DriveLetter $splitted
```

I receive the following error:

```
New-Partition : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'DriveLetter'. Cannot convert the "System.String[]" value of type "System.String[]" to type 
"System.Char".
```

any suggestion please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it and determine `$freeletter` like this:

```
[char]$freeletter = (get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | select -expand DeviceID -Last 1)[0]
```